# React/Flux efficiency: how to prevent an action from triggering multiple renders of a component?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm still studying the Flux architecture, and noticed that:

- one Action can cause multiple Stores to emit a "change" event
- one ControllerView can be subscribed to the "change" event of multiple Stores

So, if ControllerView depends on data of two Stores, and those two Stores are both changed by one Action, the ContollerView - with all its components - will be rendered (to the virtual DOM) twice, the first time with incomplete data.

Is there any recognized pattern to avoid this? I can think of some simple solutions, but I wouldn't like to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Why do you care if it renders more than once? Is it because you'd like better performance, or is it because one of the renders will leave the component in an inconsistent state?

Comment: @GJK because of inconsistent state

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should just allow it to render more than once. However, the if the action always triggers actions in both stores you can use the ["waitFor()" method of the dispatcher](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/dispatcher.html) to let one store update first, then only emit a change when the second store gets updated.

This is only useful if the action will always affect both stores, however.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but using waitFor will still have have two different "change" events and two different render cycles, won't it? Actually I think that using it could prevent doing the second render, but only if you also write a shouldComponentUpdate() function that is able to understand that the state didn't actually change, but that's not so obvious to do.

Have you got any citation for "you should just allow it to render more than once"? That would interest me.

Comment: Hmm, with some research I can't actually find anything that states specifically that you should allow it to render twice. I think one solution could be to create two views nested within the ControllerView, each listening to the data of only one of the stores. There would still be two renders, though.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice in flux pattern is to limit number of stateful components, and try only to have top component listen to stores, and send down all relevant info in props.

With multiple stores, one solution to minimize multiple renders after a single change:

- create a StatStore that stores nothing, but listens to all relevant Actions, and waits for all other relevant stores.
- this StatStore has getter functions, that collect (and possibly calculates stats) from other stores
- your top component only listens to StatStore change emissions
- top component then gets data from StatStore.

That way, a single change only results in one re-render.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this looks like a big departure from how Flux should work...

Comment: Which part of the answer would deviate from Flux? Their own tutorial (chat) works in a similar way. The additional StatStore does not deviate from flux. In my view such a store is a nice and clean solution to a) keep track of stores listening dispatches and b) preventing circular waitFor cycles.

Comment: Facebook chat components listen to two stores: componentDidMount: function() {
    this._scrollToBottom();
    MessageStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
    ThreadStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
  }

Comment: So which part of the answer do you think violates flux pattern?

Comment: Step 1, "create a StatStore that stores nothing, ...". Anyway, I've got nothing against this solution if it works for you. It just isn't what I was looking for - and since then we have switched to Redux, so obviously I don't care about "Flux purity" anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add this for future reference: I didn't find any good solution to this problem with vanilla Flux, and in the end switched to [Redux](https://github.com/rackt/redux), which has all the advantages of Flux and doesn't suffer from this disadvantage.